# Set up Accumulo table through api

Tags: java, accumulo

new to Accumulo, and this may sound silly, but I was wondering how to setup a table through the api? The documentation is definitely lacking. I have been able to find

```
conn.tableOperations().createTable("myTable");
```

as well as like setting up locality groups:

```
HashSet<Text> metadataColumns = new HashSet<Text>();
metadataColumns.add(new Text("domain"));
metadataColumns.add(new Text("link"));

HashSet<Text> contentColumns = new HashSet<Text>();
contentColumns.add(new Text("body"));
contentColumns.add(new Text("images"));

localityGroups.put("metadata", metadataColumns);
localityGroups.put("content", contentColumns);

conn.tableOperations().setLocalityGroups("mytable", localityGroups);

Map<String, Set<Text>> groups =
    conn.tableOperations().getLocalityGroups("mytable");
```

From the documentation, but I want to know how to take the first approach and build the table. Then build the columns.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you talking about defining a schema/mapping for the table? could you elaborate? Thanks

Comment: Sorry. I mean I guess how do you declare the columns and associate them with the table?

Comment: You don't have to declare the columns in advance.

Comment: Yeah, your right sorry. Still in the relational db mindset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no inherent schema for a table to set up. Once it is created using the API you found, you can insert whatever key-value pairs you wish in it.